# Hiding some parts of a html table with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Consider the following snippet:

```js
jQuery(".zoekopcat").on("keyup", function() {
  var value = jQuery(this).val();

  jQuery("table tr").each(function(index) {
    if (index !== 0) {
      row = jQuery(this);

      var id = row.find("strong:contains(" + value + ")").text();

      if (id.indexOf(value) !== -1) {
        row.show();
      } else {
        row.hide();
      }
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="zoekopcat">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=7><strong>Face</strong</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Product1</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Product2</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=7><strong>Hands</strong</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Product1</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Product2</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If for example I type "Face" in the search field,
I want it to show the tr td with "Face" and product 1 and 2 of "Face",
products of "Hands" should be hidden....,
and if I type "Hands", "Face" and it products should be hidden, etc....

I have the following jQuery code working already, but if I type "Face" in the searchfield, it's showing "Face" but not the corresponding product 1 and 2....

Now I should show product 1 and 2 also and hide all the rest...

Comment: Unrelated but your HTML is badly formed in a couple of places: `<td colspan=7><strong>Face</strong</td>`.  `</strong` is missing the closing `>`

Comment: Do you accept an answer with some tweaks in this html code? Because currently it's kinda available but this is bad modelling. You should group your products like for example using data attrs or something. Then what you want is gonna be much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I've fixed a minor error with the HTML where your `strong` tags were not terminated correctly. In addition, I removed the check for the first row as this meant that `Face` would always be shown regardless of the search value.

In order to resolve this problem, I use a boolean variable `shouldShow` to indicate whether the current row should be shown.

The code iterates through the table rows as previously, and then verifies whether the current row contains a `strong` tag.  If it does, it determines whether this matches what is being searched for and sets `shouldShow` appropriately.

`shouldShow` is then used to determine whether to show or hide the row.  See the working snippet below:

```js
jQuery(".zoekopcat").on("keyup", function() {
  var value = jQuery(this).val();
  var shouldShow = false;
  
  jQuery("table tr").each(function(index) {
    row = jQuery(this);

    if (row.find("strong").length) {
      var id = row.find("strong:contains(" + value + ")").text();

      if (id.indexOf(value) !== -1) {
        shouldShow = true;
      } else {
        shouldShow = false;
      }
    }
    
    if (shouldShow) {
      row.show();
    } else {
      row.hide();
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="zoekopcat">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=7><strong>Face</strong></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Product1</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Product2</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=7><strong>Hands</strong></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Product1</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Product2</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding an identifying `data`-attribute to the rows helps a lot and makes the JavaScript code very simple.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="zoekopcat">
<table>
  <tr data-category="Face">
    <td colspan="7"><strong>Face</strong></td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-category="Face">
    <td>Product1</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
   <tr data-category="Face">
    <td>Product2</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-category="Hands">
    <td colspan="7"><strong>Hands</strong></td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-category="Hands">
    <td>Product3</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
   <tr data-category="Hands">
    <td>Product4</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

JavaScript:

```
jQuery(".zoekopcat").on("keyup", function() {
  var value = jQuery(this).val();

  jQuery("table tr").each(function() {
    var rowCat = $(this).data('category');
    if (rowCat.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
        $(this).show();
    } else {
        $(this).hide();
    }
  });
});
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/bkxLf3p0/

**Edit:** I added `toLowerCase()` to the string comparison (= case insensitive search) as it seemed useful to me

Comment: I tested Martin's code and it's working but I presume your answer is also correct....

Answer (score 2):

Here's a jquery solution using `.nextUntil`.

1. gets all of the "header" rows (in this case that have `strong` in the first td)
2. finds the one(s) that match the input
3. hides all the rows (start with a clean slate)
4. loops through each matching header row
5. uses .nextUntil to find the next header row (but not including it (as in "until"))
6. shows the rows between

```js
$(".zoekopcat").on("keyup", function() {
  var val = $(this).val().toUpperCase();

  var headerRows = $("table tr td:first-child>strong").closest("tr");
  var matchRows = headerRows.filter((i,e) => 
                    $(e).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(val) >= 0);
  $("table tr").hide();
  matchRows.each(function() {
    $(this).show().nextUntil(headerRows).show();
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="zoekopcat">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=7><strong>Face</strong></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Product1</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Product2</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=7><strong>Hands</strong></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Product1</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Product2</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```